# Executar método no form1 para alteração no form2

Tags: c#, sql, método

Estou desenvolvendo um gerenciador de estoque, e os dados estão sendo armazenados em um banco de dados. O problema que estou enfrentando é o seguinte: quando eu adiciono um novo produto por exemplo, criei um botão "Atualizar lista" (deixei em vermelho na imagem), que quando o usuário clica nele, ele atualiza o ListView e mostra o novo produto inserido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece o seguinte, quando a pessoa clica em "Novo produto" (para adicionar um novo produto), abre uma nova form para fazer o cadastro.
O que eu estou tentando fazer, é atualizar a ListView dos produtos (que está no form1), quando o usuário cadastra um produto pelo form2.
Eu já tentei instanciar a classe da form1 e chamar o método, não da erro nenhum, porem a ListView dos produtos não atualiza. Como posso resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método para atualizar a ListView que eu estou usando:

```
// Método para atualizar a ListView Produtos
public void RefreshList()
{
    // Limpar o campo da List View
    listView_Cliente.Items.Clear();

    // Lógica para atualizar a list view
    con.Open();
    cmdListView = new SqlCommand("select * from produtos", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdListView);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "estoque");

    con.Close();
    dt = ds.Tables["estoque"];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        listView_Cliente.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        // temos 4 colunas (sendo uma a ID), então aqui só criamos 3, a ID vai automática
        listView_Cliente.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
        listView_Cliente.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
        listView_Cliente.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString());
        listView_Cliente.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString());

    }
}
```

Basicamente então instanciei a classe do form1 (que está o método para atualizar o ListView) para o form2, lá eu chamei o método para atualizar o ListView, o Visual Studio não apresentou erros, porem, o List View não atualiza. Tentei fazer de outras maneiras em algumas postagens gringas que eu vi, porem, também sem sucesso. Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Já tentou chamar o método de atualizar lista no final do método cadastrar?

Comment: Tentei, também não da erro, mas não atualiza. Será que tenho que fazer alguma mudança no código para que ele identifique que a ListView que quero atualizar está em outro form?
Estou fazendo dessa maneira:
1. Instancio a classe que possuí o método e a List View: 
TelaLogado atualizarEstoque = new TelaLogado();
2. Chamo o método no objeto instanciado (dentro do método de cadastrar):
atualizarEstoque.RefreshList()

Comment: Você não precisa executar o `Bind()` do componente após atualizar seus itens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todas as respostas. O que ocorreu é que meu caso em específico eu abria a form2 e mantinha a form1 aberta. Quem fechava no final era a form2 somente. Enfim, eu consegui atualizar a ListView passando por parâmetro e abrindo a form1 novamente (meio gambi), porem, a form1 ficava aberta em duplicidade, e não conseguia fechar a duplicidade.
Como fiquei um tempão preso nesse problema, precisei ser objetivo na solução (vi na NET que outro meio de resolver isso é através de BIND, caso eu alguém precise).

Eu resolvi da seguinte forma, na hora de abrir a form2, ao invés de usar somente "form2.Show()", usei "form2.ShowDialog()", e na sequência chamei o método que atualiza minha ListView. QUando usa o ShowDialog(), assim que fecho a form2, ele chama esse método e atualiza a Lista. Não é exatamente o que eu estava pensando, mas já melhorou muito o funcionamento do programa, e cumpriu o objetivo principal que era retirar o botão para o usuário ficar atualizando a lista. Assim que sobrar um tempo maior vou estudar sobre o BIND

Como ficou o código:

```
AddProduct telaProduto = new AddProduct();
            telaProduto.ShowDialog();
            RefreshList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Como um primeiro passo, ao inves de fazer new Form1(), na hora que voce faz new Form2(), passa por parametro a listView_Cliente, assim voce vai estar passando por referencia (quando se passa um objeto por parâmetro, no C# é padrão passar por referência) esse componente do Form1, assim quando voce alterar algo nele, vai refletir na instancia original do Form1.
Uma coisa interessante de entender nesse caso é que cada instancia tem 'vida própria', entao se criar uma nova instancia de Form1, não vai afetar a instancia anterior de Form1. Entender isso já é um grande passo para entender o 'runtime', da utilidade de se ter ou não novas instancias, e a importância de passar parametros por referência.

Despois que conseguir acertar, existe formas mais "elegantes" de tratar isso,  como usar delegates, é bom ver para depois entender até como algumas coisas funcionam no windows forms.